# WorkFlow Content type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I created a copy from **reusable workflow**, I select `Event` as content type

I need to change content type to `ALL` without copy and modify again!

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Once you have selected the `base content type` you can't change it. I suggest continuing reading [LIMITATIONS ON MODIFYING CONTENT TYPES VIA SHAREPOINT DESIGNER REUSABLE WORKFLOWS](https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/12/12/limitations-on-modifying-content-types-via-sharepoint-designer-reusable-workflows/)

**The available workaround is**

- Right Click on your Reusable workflow > Select Copy & Modify.
- And select the content type that you need.

[image]